# React componentDidMount causing initial flickering on conditional views

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, design-patterns, frontend

I am implementing a persistent login design on my react app.

My app will store in localStorage a token from the previous login. On app startup I need to decode/validate this token and persist their login. If a user is logged in then they see the home page, otherwise they see the landing page. The issue is that my app will initially flicker from being in a "not logged in" state to a "logged in state" which means the app is initially in the landing page for a few milliseconds and then it is in the home page. This flicker is a bit jarring and certainly not a good ux.

Should I have an initial loading screen or is there a better way to handle this conditional view scenario.

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        isAuthenticated: false,
        username: null
    };

    this.dispatch = this.dispatch.bind(this);
};

componentDidMount(){
    const token = localStorage.token;
    if (token){
        axios.get('api/users/getUser', {headers: {
            "Authorization": token
        }})
        .then(res => {
            this.dispatch(this.state, {
                type: 'LOGIN', payload: res.data
            })
        })
    }
}

render(){
    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider
            value = {{
                'state': this.state,
                'dispatch': this.dispatch
            }}
        >
            <div className='App'>
                {!this.state.isAuthenticated ? <LandingPage /> : <Home />}
            </div>
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    )
};
```

Comment: You can add a third condition that checks a loading state that you set before you try to authenticate the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement a spinner indicating the client is getting authorized by adding a component state before fetching the token.

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        isAuthenticated: false,
        isAuthenticating: false,
        username: null,

    };

    this.dispatch = this.dispatch.bind(this);
};

componentDidMount(){
    const token = localStorage.token;
    if (token){
        this.setState({ isAuthenticating: true })
        axios.get('api/users/getUser', {headers: {
            "Authorization": token
        }})
        .then(res => {
            this.dispatch(this.state, {
                type: 'LOGIN', payload: res.data
            })
            this.setState({ isAuthenticating: false })
        })
    }
}

render(){
    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider
            value = {{
                'state': this.state,
                'dispatch': this.dispatch
            }}
        >
            <div className='App'>
                {this.state.isAuthenticating ? <Spinner /> : null }
                {!this.state.isAuthenticated ? <LandingPage /> : <Home />}
            </div>
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    )
};
```

Comment: Thanks that makes sense. I wasn't sure if that was the correct design pattern since my "loading" takes a very short time. But I could see myself adding more stuff to preload in the future so this seems like a good solution